# How can I make this recursive function asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websitespark

```
function SetText(gg = `textttttt `, cmd = `sudo --info`) {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('demo').length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        var speed = 60;

        document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML = `<code class="shell-session demo hljs nginx"><span class="hljs-attribute">Website</span> <span class="hljs-regexp">~ $</span> ${cmd}`;

        function typeItOut() {
            if (i < gg.length) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML += gg.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeItOut, speed);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(typeItOut, 1800);
    }
}
```

so that's the code, I want every time I click a button on my website it waits until the recursive finish then starts another one...

Comment: So it something calls SetText a second time it waits until the first time finishes?

Comment: yea that exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)?

If you can, this will make it much easier to  in effect "pause" each iteration through your string by a given timeout duration (see the `handleIterateString` class function below).

This async `handleIterateString` function will "pause" at each `await` keyword, and wait until the promise returned by the `await` expression has been resolved. Only then will it continue executing the `async` function.

Also, you can "pause" the execution of the `async` function where you initiate a new complete iteration through your string (see the `await demo.handleIterateString` call inside the `async function SetText` below.

In this way, you can wait for the entire iteration (i.e. typing behaviour) to finish **before** decrementing your click queue count.

If you have click events left in your queue, you can at that point call `SetText` recursively.

---

**Simply put:** using `async/await` makes it much easier to both control the speed of the typing behaviour, and wait for your typing behaviour to complete before doing anything else.

Try running the code snippet below.

```js
class Typer {
  /**
   * @description delays execution for a given amount of time
   * @param {number} ms - time in milliseconds
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   *
   * @private
   */
  #delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  /**
   * @description html for for displaying queue information
   * @returns {{hasQueue: string, noQueue: string}}
   * @private
   */
  get #html() {
    return {
      hasQueue: `Click events waiting in queue: <span class="tag is-danger is-light is-large">${this.state.queueCount}</span>`,
      noQueue: 'Queue is clear',
    };
  }

  /**
   * @description renders queue count information
   * @returns {void}
   * @private
   */
  #renderCountText = () => {
    const hasQueue = this.state.queueCount > 0;

    const fn = hasQueue ? 'add' : 'remove';
    document.getElementById('type-btn').classList[fn]('is-danger');

    const htmlContent = this.#html[hasQueue ? 'hasQueue' : 'noQueue'];
    this.render(htmlContent, '.queueCount');
  };

  /**
   * @description accepts a html selector string
   * @param {string} selector
   */
  constructor(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
  }

  /**
   * @description state of typer instance
   * @const {{queueCount: number, speed: number}}
   * @public
   */
  state = {
    queueCount: -1,
    speed: 30,
  };

  /**
   * @description appends a html string to the instance's html element
   * @param {string} html
   * @returns {void}
   * @public
   */
  append = (html) => {
    document.querySelector(this.selector).innerHTML += html;
  };

  /**
   * @description renders given html string inside element with given selector
   * @param {string} html
   * @param {string} [el]
   * @returns {void}
   * @public
   */
  render = (html, el = this.selector) => {
    document.querySelector(el).innerHTML = html;
  };
  /**
   * @description confirms existence of the instance's selector in the DOM
   * @returns {boolean}
   * @public
   */
  exists = () => !!document.querySelector(this.selector);

  /**
   * @description
   * - iterates through the passed string and calls
   *   the passed listener on each character in the string
   * - waits for the given time from the state's 'speed' property,
   *   before proceeding to the next iteration
   *
   * @param {string} string
   * @param {string} listener - function to call on each character of string
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   *
   * @async
   * @public
   */
  handleIterateString = async (string, listener) => {
    for (let i of string) {
      listener(i);
      await this.#delay(this.state.speed);
    }
  };

  /**
   * @description increments the queue count in the state by one
   * @public
   * @returns {void}
   */
  incrementQueue = () => {
    this.state.queueCount++;
    this.#renderCountText();
  };

  /**
   * decrements the queue count in the state by one
   * @public
   * @returns {void}
   */
  decrementQueue = () => {
    this.state.queueCount--;
    this.#renderCountText();
  };
}

// instantiate demo
const demo = new Typer('.demo');

async function SetText(
  gg = `the puppy goes woof  woof woof woof...`,
  cmd = `sudo --info`
) {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
  if (demo.exists()) {
    const html = `<code class="shell-session demo hljs nginx"><span class="hljs-attribute">Website</span> <span class="hljs-regexp">~ $</span> ${cmd}`;

    // render HTML container
    demo.render(html);

    // do typing
    await demo.handleIterateString(gg, demo.append);

    demo.decrementQueue();

    if (demo.state.queueCount >= 0) {
      SetText();
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('type-btn').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  if (demo.state.queueCount === -1) {
    SetText();
  }
  demo.incrementQueue();
});
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.select-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.queueCount {
  min-height: 40px;
}

.demo {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form mb-3">
    <button class="button is-primary" id="type-btn">
    <span>Click me</span>
    </button>

    <div class="select-box">
      <label>speed per character (ms)</label>
      <div class="select">
        <select></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="content is-normal mb-3">
    <div class="queueCount is-size-5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content is-normal">
    <div class="demo is-size-5"></div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- demo select menu -->
<script>
  const select = document.querySelector('select');
  Array.from({
      length: 50,
    },
    (_, i) => (i + 1) * 30
  ).forEach((num) => {
    select.innerHTML += `<option value="${num}">${num}</option>`;
  });

  select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    demo.state.speed = parseInt(document.querySelector('select').value, 10);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to create a queue which is essentialy just an array where you push the text you want to display after you click. Then keep processing the queue until it's empty.

The code could look like this

```
function SetText(gg = `textttttt `, cmd = `sudo --info`) {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('demo').length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        var speed = 60;

        document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML = `<code class="shell-session demo hljs nginx"><span class="hljs-attribute">Website</span> <span class="hljs-regexp">~ $</span> ${cmd}`;

        function typeItOut() {
            if (i < gg.length) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML += gg.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeItOut, speed);
            } else {
                processing = false; // add this
                next();             // and this
            }
        }
        setTimeout(typeItOut, 1800);
    }
}

var processing = false;
var queue = [];

function click() {
    queue.push([gg, cmd]); // get gg and cmd somehow
    next();
};

function next() {
    if (processing || !queue.length)
        return;

    processing = true;

    var args = queue.shift(); // get first item from queue
    SetText(args[0], args[1]);
};
```

I haven't tested it so it might not work but you should get the idea.

Comment: it did not work, I am aware that I should do something like a query however I am not managing to do it